# How to process 1 millions of CSV/Excel records in minutes and insert in DB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Use Case: The user will upload a file of 1 million CSV/excel records and we have to process those records in less time and insert those records into the Database.

Our Implementation:

1. File Uploads To S3
2. Lambda Function[Func1] get triggers
3. Func1 converts CSV into JSON and divides it into chunks of 10K
4. Then the chunks get pushed in AWS SQS
5. Lambda Function[Func2] get triggers when something comes in AWS SQS
6. Func2 receives the data and insert it into DB and delete the data from AWS SQS

Need your suggestions if this thing is a good choice or not?

Comment: why JSON and SQS at all? do a bulk insert / copy in the first lamdba. it would be highly useful to know which database brand you're using and whether or not it's on RDS

Comment: How often are you doing this? Is it once per day, or continuously throughout the day? What is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

you made an architecture choices (sqs) and you should be able to justify them. I mean - the idea is not bad, but you should be aware of the tradeoffs and consequences.

> File Uploads To S3 
> Lambda Function[Func1] get triggers 
> Func1 converts CSV into JSON and divides it into chunks of 10K 
> Then the chunks get pushed in AWS SQS

I see no reason to convert data to json

You decided to SQS which adds resiliency, but as well adds some complexity and delays. It's up to you to decide what is more important. Good call to use reasonable chunks to process, let's keep lamdas short.

However, if you have REALY large files,  the delays added may be significant and you would  be better off with AWS Batch jobs.  1M lines is not so much, a proper batch upload should handle that in a few seconds.

> Lambda Function[Func2] get triggers when something comes in AWS SQS 
> Func2 receives the data and insert it into DB and delete the data from AWS SQS

And here you should see what the bottleneck is and as well  be aware of parallelism. If you are using some default Sql DB, then executing multiple lamdas with inserts at once may be even slower than a single batch insert.